# Plot with TikZ (Fermi distribution)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, plot, overleaf, distributions

any idea on how to do these two figures with TikZ? Especially the one on the right :)

Thanks a lot!!

[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far? it's recommend that you provide a minimal working example. At least you have fomular for Fermi distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics and you can check how to plot in Section 22.5 Plotting a Function of PGF manual https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Hello, I was looking for some hints on how to do the graph in the right. For instance, the function to be plotted.

Comment: I see your point, but I'm not an expert and probably it is worth to ask to people that can do this simple thing in 5 minutes. That's how I have learnt to use Latex/TikZ: start from what other did, and from here produce my own figure with the details I needed etc etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bezier curves are a possible solution (but not the only one, you can also use `to[bend=right]` for example).

[image: Fermi distribution]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[<->,>={Stealth[scale=1.5]}] (0,4) node[above left] {$n(k)$} |- (5,0) node[below right] {$k$};
        \draw[dotted,cap=round,line width=0.5pt] (0,3) -| (3,0) node [below] {$k_F$};
        \draw[line width=2pt,red]
            (0,3) .. controls ++ (1,0) and ++ (-1,0.7) ..
            (3,2.2) --
            (3,1) .. controls ++ (0.5,-.5) and ++ (-0.5,0) ..
            (4.8,0.2);  
        \draw[xshift=3mm,<->,>={Stealth[scale=1]},line width=0.5pt] (3,1) -- (3,2.2) node[midway,right] {\Large Z};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That's what I was looking for. Cheers!!

Comment: Don't hesitate to vote and accept the answer, so ;)

Comment: just did it... again, my thesis thanks you ahah